# Value of Text Input not showing via developer app

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am creating a basic currency conversion application using `Phonegap 6.5.0` and `fixer.io`. The issue I am having is that the quote/conversion value that is set into a `disabled` text input is not visible when viewing the app via the Phonegap app on my Nexus 6p. If I view the page via the server on my desktop I see the value. Additionally, if I enable the input as a test, nothing changes, but I can confirm that I do see the text if I type in that field.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Currency Conversion</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- The main page of the application -->
        <div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content-main" class="ui-content" data-role="main">

                <form id = "currency-conversion" action="" method="POST">

                    <!-- Base Currency -->
                    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
                        <legend>Base Currency</legend>

                        <select id="base" name="base">
                            <option value="CAD" selected>CAD</option>
                            <option value="USD">USD</option>
                        </select>
                        <input id="base-value" name="base-value" type="text">
                    </fieldset>

                    <!-- Quote Currency -->
                    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
                        <legend>Quote Currency</legend>

                        <select id="quote" name="quote">
                            <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                            <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
                        </select>
                        <input id="quote-value" name="quote-value" type="text" disabled>
                    </fieldset>

                    <!-- Buttons -->
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><button id="clear" data-theme="c">Clear</button></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="convert" type="submit" data-theme="b">Convert</button></div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scripts after page load -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/convert.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#convert").click(function() {
        // Gather input
        var base = $("#base").val();
        var quote = $("#quote").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://api.fixer.io/latest?callback=?&base=" + base + "&symbols=" + quote,
            data: {},
            async: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossOrigin: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response.rates[quote]);

                var result = ($("#base-value").val() * response.rates[quote]);
                $("#quote-value").val("" + result.toFixed(2));
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

    // Clear the form input fields
    $("#clear").click(function() {
        $("#currency-conversion").find("input[type=text]").val("");
    });
});
```